# Handling array of objects response using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

At the risk of asking this question for the 11 time, I'm having issues **handling a response from a POST request**. And haven't been able to get any of the example found of stackoverflow to work.

I'm making a simple request to my backend which returns an **array of json objects**.

The error I'm getting is. .

`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Here's exactly what I'm doing

**WebAPIService.class**

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("pendingTransfers")
Call<List<VehicleTransferData>> refreshVehicles(@Body VehicleTransferData msg);
```

**the Activity**

```
public void refreshCars(View view) {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(TRANSFER_API)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    WebAPIService client = retrofit.create(WebAPIService.class);

    setTestData();

    Call<List<VehicleTransferData>> call = client.refreshVehicles(vtData);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<VehicleTransferData>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<VehicleTransferData>> call, Response<List<VehicleTransferData>> response) {

            Toast.makeText(RegisteredVehicles.this, response.body().get(0).getVehicleReg(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<VehicleTransferData>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisteredVehicles.this, t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

RESPONSE DATA FROM SERVER

```
{ResponseCode=200, ResponseMessage=ok, ApiVersion=v1, ResponsePackage=[
  {
    "transferUUID":"TRANSFER-UUID-5678-0000-567812345678",
    "vehicleUUID":"0VEHICLE-UUID-5678-0000-567812345678",
    "vehicleRegUUID":"VEHICLER-UUID-5678-0000-567812345678",
    "vehicleReg":"j107",
    "status":"pending",
    "transferDate":"2099-12-3",
    "seller":{
      "personUUID":"00SELLER-UUID-5678-0000-567812345678",
      "signature":"%3FR%3FD%3FV%3F%344DX54F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3FBOOT-INF%2Flib%2FasmPK%0D%0A",
      "mileage":39993,"timestamp":"2099-12-31T23:59:59"
    },
    "buyer":{
      "personUUID":"000BUYER-UUID-5678-0000-567812345678",
      "signature":"Alfred Schmidt",
      "mileage":3993,
      "timestamp":"time"
    }
  }
]}
```

Comment: Could you please also attach your response json? Possibly your server returns json-object, that contains that array

Comment: seems your response is an object in place of an array.

Comment: added to the bottom of the post. I think the fields at the beginning are causing the issue then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that truly is the response from server then you need to create a class that looks like this:

```
class VehicleResponse{
    int ResponseCode;
    string ResponseMessage;
    string ApiVersion;
    List<VehicleTransferData> ResponsePackage;
}
```

API:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("pendingTransfers")
Call<VehicleResponse> refreshVehicles(@Body VehicleTransferData msg);
```

Activity:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<VehicleResponse>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<VehicleResponse> call, Response<VehicleResponse> response) {

            Toast.makeText(RegisteredVehicles.this, response.body().get(0).getVehicleReg(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<VehicleResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisteredVehicles.this, t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the code in your VehicleTransferData class?

Also maybe the JSON isn't returning an array but an object instead. If that's the case then change to:

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("pendingTransfers")
Call<VehicleTransferData> refreshVehicles(@Body VehicleTransferData msg);
```

And in activity

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<VehicleTransferData>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<VehicleTransferData> call, Response<VehicleTransferData> response) {

            Toast.makeText(RegisteredVehicles.this, response.body().get(0).getVehicleReg(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<VehicleTransferData> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisteredVehicles.this, t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```